# Public Static Vars overwrites on each other every and close requests

Tags: c#, razor

I have one micro web site structure. I am using public static vars for changing its contents by using HTTP QueryString. I have defined many public vars in App_Code. But fast and close requests by many user, public static vars value overwrites on each other and micro site contents can be wrong against QueryString value. I am using global vars in parts of cshtml file which included

App_Code

```
public class MyCommonClass
{
    public static string SitePrefix { get; set; }

    public static void SetSitePrefix(string _Prefix)
    {
        MyCommonClass.SitePrefix = _Prefix;
    }

    public static void ConfigureSite()
    {
        string _QsPrefix = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["stx"]) ? "" : HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["stx"];
        MyCommonClass.SetSitePrefix(_QsPrefix);
    }

}
```

settings.cshtml

```
@{
    if(MyCommonVars.SitePrefix == "foo")
    {
        Response.Write("Opps");
    }

}
```

index.cshtml

```
 @RenderPage("settings.cshtml")
 @RenderPage("head.cshtml")
 @RenderPage("body.cshtml")
 @RenderPage("bottom.cshtml")
```

body.cshtml

```
@{
    Response.Write(MyCommonVars.SitePrefix);
}
```

I would like to define vars on top page I mean in settings.cshtml and I would like to use that only in all cshtml files which that parts of current http request pages.

Comment: Static fields is ok for values that are read once and never change again, like values read from the web.config. It is sometimes also suitable for constant values where you do not want to use `const`.  That is about it. Otherwise you get into problems like you have above. I can't recommend a fix because you never explained `why` you are setting this to begin with. Is it passed with every request? Only when users login like a profile? Something else? At this point the only take away is "don't use static".

Comment: Why are you using static properties and methods?